# How to figure out the smallest integral type that can represent a number, in compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I need to figure out the smallest unsigned integral type that can represent a particular number, in compile time. Something like this...

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<size_t Bits>
struct uint_least{};

template<>
struct uint_least<8>{ typedef std::uint8_t type; };

template<>
struct uint_least<16>{ typedef std::uint16_t type; };

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<size_t max>
struct uint_least_bits
{
    static const size_t value = 14; // just a placeholder
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<size_t max>
class A
{
    typedef typename uint_least<uint_least_bits<max>::value>::type underlying_type;

    underlying_type m_X;
};
```

`uint_least` is meant to give you the smallest unsigned integral type that is at least `Bits` large and it should work for any value up to 64 (not just 8, 16, 32, 64 but also 1, 4, 13, etc).

`uint_least_bits` is meant to give you the minimum number of bits needed to represent `max`.

- How can I implement `uint_least`?
- How can I implement `uint_least_bits`?
- What types should `bits`, `min`, and `max` be? If the answer is a template type, how can I guard against invalid input?

**The exact structuring of the traits doesn't matter. Feel free to scrap what I provided. I just need to provide a number and get back the smallest unsigned integral type that can hold it.**

Comment: You could just use `decltype` on your integral constant.

Comment: Should `int_least_bits<255, 256>::value` be 1 or 9?

Comment: @GManNickG Good question. I would say 9, however feel free to disagree and tell me why

Comment: @Dave: Because I can encode two integer values in just one bit, zero meaning the first, one meaning the second. Basically, is this: "what type can I use to encode the values in this" or "what type can I use that would allow me to directly assign it the literal values in this range"? The word "represent" in your question is what introduces this ambiguity.

Comment: @GManNickG Okay I'll change my wording then. Thanks

Comment: @KerrekSB: `decltype` won't give you the *smallest* type for values small enough to promote to `int`.  For example, `decltype(1)` is `int`, not one of the `char` types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this just yesterday, what a coincidence. I'll leave it here, even though it's not *exactly* what you need(it fixes the best integral type thing anyway):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdint.h>

template<size_t i>
struct best_type {
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        (i <= 8),
        uint8_t,
        typename std::conditional<
            (i <= 16),
            uint16_t,
            typename std::conditional<
                (i <= 32),
                uint32_t,
                uint64_t
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type type;
};
```

Then, you'd use it like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template<size_t i>
struct best_type {
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        (i <= 8),
        uint8_t,
        typename std::conditional<
            (i <= 16),
            uint16_t,
            typename std::conditional<
                (i <= 32),
                uint32_t,
                uint64_t
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type type;
};   

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(best_type<2>::type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(best_type<8>::type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(best_type<15>::type) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(best_type<17>::type) << std::endl;
}
```

Live demo, [here](http://ideone.com/kZ8mu).

Comment: +1 But I should get credit for using `constexpr` when the OP least expected it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you've got `constexpr`, this will work:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

inline
constexpr
unsigned
clz(unsigned x)
{
    return x == 0 ? sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT : x & 0x80000000 ? 0 : 1 + clz(x << 1);
}

inline
constexpr
unsigned
clp2(unsigned x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 0 : 1 << (sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT - clz(x-1));
}

inline
constexpr
unsigned
at_least8(unsigned x)
{
    return x < 8 ? 8 : x;
}

template<size_t Bits>
struct uint_least{};

template<>
struct uint_least<8>{ typedef std::uint8_t type; };

template<>
struct uint_least<16>{ typedef std::uint16_t type; };

template<>
struct uint_least<32>{ typedef std::uint32_t type; };

template<>
struct uint_least<64>{ typedef std::uint64_t type; };

template<size_t max>
struct uint_least_bits
{
    static const size_t value = clp2(max);
};

template<size_t max>
class A
{
    typedef typename uint_least<at_least8(uint_least_bits<max>::value)>::type underlying_type;

    underlying_type m_X;
};

int main()
{
    A<3> a;
}
```

If you don't have `constexpr`, you could translate clp2 into a template meta-function (and that's left as an exercise for the reader :-)).

Oh, disclaimer:  Assumes a 32 bit `unsigned`.  That could be generalized too if needed.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think it's useless to precise `inline` when defining `constexpr` functions.

Comment: constexpr functions can still run at run time if called with non-constexpr arguments.

Comment: From the C++11 standard, section 7.1.5: `constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly inline`. Ok, that has nothing to do with the current problem. At least I've an answer for one question. Sorry for the trouble.